# How do I calculate LINEST in C# with a zero intercept?

Tags: c#, mathematical-expressions

The normal Linest is easy, but I don't know how to "b is set equal to 0 and the m-values are adjusted to fit y = mx."

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var yValues = new double[] { 1, 9, 5, 7 };
        var xValues = new double[] { 0, 4, 2, 3 };


        var noConst = Linest(yValues, xValues);
        Console.WriteLine("m = {0}, b = {1}", noConst.Slope, noConst.Intercept);


    }

    public static LineSpec Linest(IList<double> yValues, IList<double> xValues)
    {
        var yAvg = yValues.Sum() / yValues.Count;
        var xAvg = xValues.Sum() / xValues.Count;

        double upperSum = 0;
        double lowerSum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < yValues.Count; i++)
        {
            upperSum += (xValues[i] - xAvg) * (yValues[i] - yAvg);
            lowerSum += (xValues[i] - xAvg) * (xValues[i] - xAvg);
        }

        var m = upperSum / lowerSum;
        var b = yAvg - m * xAvg;
        return new LineSpec() { Slope = m, Intercept = b };
    }

}

struct LineSpec
{
    public double Slope { get; set; }
    public double Intercept { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you not know how to compute LINEST with zero-intercept? Or do you have a specific problem implementing the method you're using in C#? If the former, your question is better sourced in mathematics SE. If the latter, you should provide details on your implementation, preferably with code, and indicate where you're having problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a math question, not a coding question. [Use linear regression without the intercept term.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Linear_regression_without_the_intercept_term)

---

```
    public static LineSpec LinestConst(IList<double> yValues, IList<double> xValues)
    {
        var yAvg = yValues.Sum() / yValues.Count;
        var xAvg = xValues.Sum() / xValues.Count;

        double upperSum = 0;
        double lowerSum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < yValues.Count; i++)
        {
            upperSum += (xValues[i] * yValues[i] );
            lowerSum += (xValues[i] * xValues[i] );
        }

        var m = upperSum / lowerSum;
        var b = 0;
        return new LineSpec() { Slope = m, Intercept = b };
    }
```